# Dynamic verb condition in a Do... While (^:)

Tags: j

This question occurred to my while solving [this problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144182/numbers-with-similar-powers).

```
NB. Find the next number whose prime factorization exponents
NB. match those of the given number.

exps=. /:~@{:@(__&q:)
f=. 3 : 0
  target=. exps y
  (>:^:(-.@(target-:exps))^:_) y+1
)

f 20 NB. 28
```

Note that in order to specify the while condition of the Do... While, I first had calculate the prime exponents of the argument `y` and save that answer to `target`.  I was then able to write `-.@(target-:exps)` as the While condition.

This of course breaks the tacit style.  So I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve the same thing that my verb above achieves, but do so as a single tacit verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I approached this was to think of `f` as the centre of a dyadic fork where the left argument is `exps y` which is the unchanging comparison `target` and the right argument is `>: y` which does the initial incrementing. The next step was to use `]` at each `^:` in `f` to keep `exps` monadic. The `[` pulls in `exps y` from the left argument.

Written in tacit

```
   exps=. /:~@{:@(__&q:)
   ft=: exps >:@]^:([ -.@-: exps@])^:_ >: 
   ft 20
28
```

Comment: Terrific, thank you.  For some reason I'd assumed that `v` didn't have access to the left arg, which as you've shown is clearly not true.